# Можно ли узнать размер фонового изображения при "background-size: contain"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть блок с фоновым изображением и `background-size: contain`.
Возможно ли узнать размер изображение уже после масштабирование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получать размер блока и размер оригинала фонового изображения, а затем рассчитать итоговый размер. Примерно таким образом:

```
var img = new Image;
img.src = $('#imgBlock').css('background-image').replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");

/* размер оригинальной картинки */
var bgImgWidth = img.width;
var bgImgHeight = img.height;

/* размер блока */
var divH = $("#imgBlock").height();
var divW = $("#imgBlock").width();

/* Итого */
var finalWidth = divW > divH ? bgImgWidth/bgImgHeight * divH : divW;
var finalHeight = divH > divW ? bgImgHeight/bgImgWidth * divW : divH;
```

Пример в работе: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/0hxxauze/1/)**

Comment: Думал делать также, но потом подумал, есть прямой способ узнать сразу размеры. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

У картинок есть свойства [naturalWidth](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalwidth.asp) и [naturalHeight](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_naturalheight.asp)

Comment: Интересно, а для чего мне эти свойства?